# MySQL Finding most frequent value in multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

- Votingid  President_vote Vice_president_vote Senator_vote ...
- 1000          1023              1102             1042
- 1001         1102              1047             1102
- 1002         1023              1047             1042
- ...

So I need to find which person(id) has most votes for each position, the outcome ideally looks like this

- President_vote Vice_president_vote Senator_vote ...
- 1023             1047              1042

There are about 5 columns in my table so it is possible to find most frequent value from each column and brutally cross join them all. However, lets assume there are 5000 columns that exist in this table. How can I write a query to find out the most frequent value that appears in each columns all together? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK there is no query for doing such task without the query being dynamically generated. But let's wait if someone comes with a clever idea.

Comment: What did you try so far? How about using SELECT MAX(votes) and sorting DESCENDING, then LIMIT 1?

Comment: @Jonas I certainly can do that for individual columns. In fact I currently have all 5 column's max number separately extracted. However I have no idea how to do such thing if there are 5000 columns as I need to write 5000 separate queries,which is pretty much impossible, to do such thing.